# Copying one list to another

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of viewmodels which contains vehicle data such as this 
public IList VehicleViewModelList { get; set; } initialized to this

```
  VehicleViewModelList = new List<VehicleViewModel>();
```

which contains same property as is in the IParking_Vehicle interface i.e.

```
    string Type { get; set; }

    string Make { get; set; }

    string Model { get; set; }

    string RegNo { get; set; }

    string DriverName { get; set; }        

    string User { get; set; }
    System.DateTime Time { get; set; }

public class VehicleViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Registration is required")]
    [DisplayName("Vehicle Registration")]
    public String RegNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Make is required")]
    [DisplayName("Vehicle Make eg Jaguar etc")]
    public String Make { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Model is required")]
    [DisplayName("Vehicle Model eg XFK")]
    public String Model { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Car Type")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CarType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Car type is required")]
    [DisplayName("Vehicle Type")]
    public string CarTypeValue { get; set; }

    public VehicleViewModel()
    {
        CarType = new SelectList(new List<string>()
                   { "CompanyCar", "PersonalCar" }.AsEnumerable<string>());
    }
}
```

Now when I create a list of

```
var _parkingVehicleList = new List<IParking_Vehicle>(), 
     I want to transfer all the values from     
 VehicleViewModelList to this _parkingVehicleList.
```

So far this complains

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (_eam.No_of_Vehicles - 1); i++)
{
    _parkingVehicle.DriverName = _eam.DriverNameList[i].DriverName;
    _parkingVehicle.Active = true;
    _parkingVehicle.Make = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].Make;
    _parkingVehicle.Model = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].Model;
    _parkingVehicle.RegNo = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].RegNo;
    _parkingVehicle.Time = DateTime.Now;
    _parkingVehicle.ParkingApplication = _parkingApplication;
    _parkingVehicle.User = UserName.IntranetUser;

    _parkingVehicleList.Add(_parkingVehicle);

    //_parkingVehicleList[i].DriverName. = _eam.DriverNameList[i].DriverName;
    //_parkingVehicleList[i].Make = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].Make;
    //_parkingVehicleList[i].Model = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].Model;
    //_parkingVehicleList[i].RegNo = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].RegNo;
    //_parkingVehicleList[i].Time = DateTime.Now;
    //_parkingVehicleList[i].Type = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].CarTypeValue;
    //_parkingVehicleList[i].Active = true;
    //_parkingVehicleList[i].ParkingApplication = _parkingApplication;
    //_parkingVehicleList[i].User = UserName.IntranetUser;

}
```

_parkingVehicleList complains because of indexer..(cant figure out why?), so its commented out...

and not commented part adds the same value twice, so first values are lost..any solutions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create a new object, and then add this object to the list.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (_eam.No_of_Vehicles - 1); i++) {

   _parkingVehicle = new VehicleViewModel(); // Or any other class that is your implementation
   // The actual type of _parkingVehicle is not clear from your question

   _parkingVehicle.DriverName = _eam.DriverNameList[i].DriverName;
   // Rest of your code
```

The reason the second part of your code fails: When you create a new List<> it is not filled and has length 0. So you cannot just go to a certain index from your list.

It is also not very clear why you need to execute the assignment twice.

Comment: _parkingVehicle is injected at runtime (using Dependency), I do the first part but i get repeated i.e. the last one filled twice. Wtih regards to second part I do give it capacity but yet it still fails, i was thinking it would initialize list with that capacity and will be able to move throught index. If there were two vehicles, I want them to be added to _parkingVehiclelist which is of type parkingvehicle but the last one overwrites the previous one and I end of having two of teh same kind

Comment: And what exactly is the first part?

Comment: The capacity is just an optimalization, the list is not filled, since it can contain any object that inherits from the base class you specify. The override occurs because you do not create a new object.

Comment: the first set of vehicleviewmodel has different data to the second part, or the third part. So in _parkingVehicle.add(_parkignVehicle), I get the last data twice, rather than two different sets..

Comment: Create a new object for every object you copy! The code you show assigns the same properties to the same object over and over. So you are creating a list with the same object. (Do you understand the difference between an object and a class?) And what is this talk about parts. What exactly do you mean with a "part".

Comment: I am dealing with interfaces so I cannot create a new object, and I am using Ninject for dependency injection in constructor..so I do understand that I need a new object, trouble is how do I get two objects of the same type from Ninject, I will try Kernel.get..and see what it does..will update you

Comment: I got this done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781479/how-do-i-get-a-new-object-using-ninject-as-in-this-example. It required a kernel.Get<> as I have explained there. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`var _parkingVehicleList = new List<IParking_Vehicle>(VehicleViewModelList);` copies the list.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) are the proof.

Comment: there is no constructur that my compiler is aware of that takes class in a list constructor, the best available overload is int

Comment: You either lie or are using a too old .NET. `List` inherits from `IEnumerable` and there is a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: you are correct, but you Ienumerable has to be of same type of the list that you are creating..which is why I was surprised

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to ease your pain.

[Getting Started with AutoMapper.](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Home)

### Example:

```
_parkingVehicle = Mapper.Map<IParking_Vehicle, IParking_Vehicle>(_eam);
```

--**EDIT**--

> **You said**:
> _parkingVehicleList complains because of indexer..(cant figure out why?), so its commented out...

Unlike arrays, you need to create instances of objects in collections (in your case, `List<T>`) before you can use them using index.

Use `Insert(Int32 index, T item)` to insert an object at a specific index before using it.

### Example:

```
_parkingVehicleList.Insert(i, _parkingVehicle);

_parkingVehicleList[i].DriverName. = _eam.DriverNameList[i].DriverName;
_parkingVehicleList[i].Make = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].Make;
_parkingVehicleList[i].Model = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].Model;
_parkingVehicleList[i].RegNo = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].RegNo;
_parkingVehicleList[i].Time = DateTime.Now;
_parkingVehicleList[i].Type = _eam.VehicleViewModelList[i].CarTypeValue;
_parkingVehicleList[i].Active = true;
_parkingVehicleList[i].ParkingApplication = _parkingApplication;
_parkingVehicleList[i].User = UserName.IntranetUser;
```

Comment: I am already using automapper in many different places in my app, this doesnt work because we are transferring lists which have different types