# How do I get a new object using Ninject as in this example

Tags: c#, object, ninject, new-operator

I am in need of adding an item of type IVehicle which is injected at runtime from constructor to a for loop.

```
IVehicle vehicle;

for (int i=0;i<=someValue;i++)
{
   list.insert(i,vehicle);
   //some processing to assign values
}
```

now because Ivehicle is already injected by this time, my list has same value despite the value on view different and coming through the controller. How can I new up this object everytime

EDIT

The best way to new up this object everytime I found was to request new from the kernel that was injecting it. I am using Ninject as said earlier.

All I did was use a create a variable of type IKernel and got the constructor to inject it and then I used kernel.Get() to get a new instance. Dont know if this is the best way to go about doing this as my constructor is really greedy. :)

private IKernel _kernel;

get this injected in constructor, no need to do any bindings as Ninject already knows this.

then you can use the _kernel to get new, by using _kernel.Get<>().

Hope this helps someone..

Comment: Consider describing you problem more in detail. You want to add someValue times a vehicle or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for this scenario is to inject `Func<IVehicle>`. And add the binding below. That way you have no reference to Ninject in you production code. Furthermore this kind of factory methods are planned to be added to the next release of Ninject. The binding below will not be necessary anymore.

```
Bind<Func<IConfigurationView>>().ToMethod(ctx => (() => ctx.Kernel.Get<IConfigurationView>()));
```

Comment: Sorry could you please do me an example, how would I go about doing it in a for loop. I do my bindings in global.asax. However I m using this in my Controller in an Mvc app, and I need to new up the object in a for loop. Many thanks

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx about how Func works. As I said, just inject this delegate into your controller and call it whenever you need a new instance.

Comment: I know how Func works and I have been using it. What I dont know much about is how Ninject keeps pointing it to same memory location, when a new is required and whats the best way of doing it. I understand that I am delegating it to a func, but would it point to new memory location...an example is what I asked for. I have two levels of binding in my huge framework and therefore wanted a quick example to make sure this thing, before i go about changing it..

Comment: The Func will create a new instance using ninject everytime you call it. It's basically a new. Just try!

Comment: I will give this a try, and update and mark answer, what I am concerned is if it has any sideeffects in a webapp...could you please also give me a quick example of conditional binding so if I have an interface ISomething<T>, i want it to bind it to something based on what T is..which is also further coming from ninject..thanks again.